# Найти третье число с конца и добавить перед ним пробел

Tags: javascript, html

Нужен разделитель тысячных на js- находим третье число с конца и добавляем перед ним пробел, подскажите как реализовать.
Например я получаю 15000 руб. , но хочу видеть 15 000 руб. Желательно с комментариями.

Comment: Уточните, у вас есть просто число, которое надо отформатировать, или же строка, в которой кроме числа есть уже и другие символы? Пока все ответы отвечают на 1-й вариант

Answer (score 4):

Например так:

```js
console.log(parseFloat(15000).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1 ").replace('.', ',')+"руб.")
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var str = "15000";

alert(str.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 '));
```

Answer (score 3):

Могу ошибаться, конечно, но складываюется впечатление, что вы хотите добавить разделитель тысяч в число. В русском языке обычно принято разделять их пробелом. Если так, то несколько странно, что отделять вы хотите только тысячи, а миллионы не хотите. Замечу, что в других языках, например, английском для разделения используется запятая.

Для форматирования чисел к стадартам применяемым в клиентской локали применяется метод `.toLocaleString()`. Если у вас дана именно строка с числом, `15000 руб.`, то извлечь число и заменить его на нужный формат.

```js
var v = 15000;
console.log( v + ' => ' + v.toLocaleString());


v = "15000 руб.";

console.log(
    v + ' => ' + v.replace(/(\d+)/, function(d){  return (+d).toLocaleString(); })
);
```

Comment: Эффективно, но скучновато :)))

Comment: @yar85 уж извините, как получилось :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
input.oninput = e => console.log(
  parseFloat(input.value)
    .toFixed(2)
    .split('.')
    .reduce((result, part) => result
            ? result + ',' + (part || '00')
            : part.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ')
    ,'')
)
```

```html
<input id=input type=numer />
```

Comment: А можно комментарии добавить? я не очень понимаю что написано

Answer (score 1):

Для коллекции, добавлю оптимизированный вариант:

```js
function foo(x, digits = 0) {
  x = String(x); 
  if (+x < 1000)
    return x.toFixed(digits); 
  let result   = [],  
      fraction = (+x % 1).toFixed(digits).slice(1).replace('.', ','), 
      integer  = String(Math.floor(+x)), 
      lastIdx  = integer.length - 1; 
  for (var i = 0; i <= lastIdx; i++) {
    if (!!i && i <= lastIdx && !(i % 3)) 
      result.push(' '); 
    result.push(integer.charAt(lastIdx - i)); 
  }
  return result.reverse().join('') + fraction; 
}

console.log(foo(42000000)); 
console.log(foo(12345.6789, 2));
```

---

Посмотреть скорость выполнения всех вариантов (на момент написания ответа) можно тут:
[<kbd>`Тест на JSperf`</kbd>](https://jsperf.com/questions-838968/1)

---

*<sub>По итогу теста в мобильном Хроме - регулярки довольно быстры, и вариант `regExp2` показывает лучший результат (хоть он и [некорректно обрабатывает вещественные числа](http://jsbin.com/wagehaledi/edit?js,console), в вопросе о них речи не было).</sub>*

Comment: Конечно, "оптимизированный" - это очень относительно. Для того чтобы по-настоящему оптимизировать, желательно избавиться от `floor`, `toFixed`, `reverse`, и `join`. Но мне было интересно проверить именно то, насколько быстрым будет реализация через `for`, не доходя до крайностей.